# Plotting Vector Embeddings

Tags: data-visualization, graphical-model, euclidean

I am currently working on a project that requires some form of data on the paper. Even though I was able to get some coding done and communicate results, I need some graphs.

What I want to do is graph the embeddings that Facenet outputs. But how can I do this?

The embedding is just a 128 x 1 vector.
[image]

I can find the L2 distance of two embeddings from each other but I want to plot the data. There isn't any X or Y coordinate that tells me where to put the "points"

I was also thinking of using this thing called PCA but I don't know the theories behind that (yet)

Comment: One mathematical definition of a vector $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ (that is implicit in the very indexing used to name it) is that it's a map from $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ into the ground field (real numbers, here).  *You can plot the graph of that map.*

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow...

Comment: By definition, the graph is the set of ordered pairs $\{(1,x_1), (2,x_2), \ldots, (n,x_n)\}.$ Some of the effective visualization methods for such graphs include scatterplots, bar charts, and dot plots.